# Is 'hoc' ever pronounced short?

Tags: classical-latin, pronunciation, pronouns

I have learned that the neuter nominative and accusative *hoc* is actually pronounced as if it were *hocc*.
But was it exclusively *hocc*?
Was it ever pronounced as the *hoc* that it looks like in the classical era?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on metric evidence, it was always pronounced "*hocc*" with a geminated *c*, but still spelled *hoc*.

I went through [all the 124 appearances of the *hoc* in Virgil's works](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23hoc%23+%5Bverg%5D).
Whenever *hoc* was followed by a vowel, the scansion unambiguously required that the syllable be long.
Many of the 124 instances occurred before consonants and there were cases of the ablative *hōc*, but there was still a substantial amount of cases of the nominative or accusative before a vowel.

I also checked about half of the [552 appearances of *hoc* in Ovid's works](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23hoc%23+%5Bov%5D&first=81), and the conclusion was identical.
There were plenty of cases where the length (weight) of the sole syllable of *hoc* was visible before a vowel, and in every single case the syllable had to be scanned long.
Therefore I feel I can confidently conclude that one always pronounced *hoc* with a geminated (long) *c* in classical Latin.

This gemination concerns pronunciation of *hoc* before a vowel.
Metric evidence will tell nothing about the length of the *c* when followed by another consonant.
It is possible that the *c* was short in such cases, or that the length was not such a meaningful concept in that context.
The pronoun is scanned long anyway in poetry.